# How to robustly copy text to char* without any errors

Tags: c, string, malloc, strcpy, strncpy

I have 2 questions..

1. is it necessary to add a termination character when executing the following commands against a `char *string` ?

   `strcpy();`

   `strncpy();`
2. Is it necessary to allocate memory before before doing any operation with the above to function against the `char *string` ?

for example..

```
char *str;
str = malloc(strlen(texttocopy));
strcpy(texttocopy, str); // see the below edit
```

Please explain.

**EDIT :** 
in the above code I inverted the argument. it is just typo i made while asking the question here. The correct way should be

```
strcpy(str, texttocopy); // :)
```

Comment: noted.. I was hurry to read the below answer that was edited each second. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function always adds the terminator, but [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) may not do it in some cases.

And for the second question, yes you need to make sure there is enough memory allocated for the destination. In your example you have *not* allocated enough memory, and will have a buffer overflow. Remember that [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) returns the length of the string *without* counting the terminator. You also have inverted the arguments to `strcpy`, the destination is the *first* argument.

Comment: I hae put `malloc(strlen(texttocopy))` . this will not allocate enough memory? So according to you,, do i need to change it as `malloc(strlen(texttocopy) + 1)` ?

Comment: @BlueBird You need `strlen(texttocopy) + 1`

Comment: @BlueBird And change the arguments for the `strcpy` call.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'strcpy' function copies data from source to destination address including with '\0' termination character . 'strncpy' function copies data as the same way but if there is no termination character '\0' exists in the first n bytes to be copied, termination character will not be copied then and you will need to add it by yourself to terminate the string.
2. You will always have to statically or dynamically allocate a memory space to play with. Therefore, you should declare a character array or dynamically allocate a chunk of memory first then you can play nice with your strings

Comment: Let's say you need 10 bytes for instance: Static allocation: char buf[10]; Dynamic allocation: char* buf = (char*) malloc(10);